# Getting some ether from somewhere

Tags: rinkeby

I wonder how to get some ether for development testing.

1. https://faucet.rinkeby.io is not working - even after I tweeted my account id and gave the twitter url. It kept saying couldn't find ethereum url or something.
2. https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet keeps returning "Our faucet is currently running low on this network. Please try again later."

Now, I'm even thinking of getting some ether for money but for $1 or so. Where can I get ether ?

I am using MetaMask.

Comment: Hey, we have recently added more funds to our testnets from some donations: https://twitter.com/MyCrypto/status/1346539474725945344

Answer (score 0):

The facuets are not perfect and do have issues sometimes. Unfortunately, outside of 'knowing a guy', you're stuck waiting for the faucets to work.

Comment: Any chance of getting a paid ether from rinkeby ?

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: Like , buying $5 worth of Rinkeby ether.

Answer (score 0):

we have recently added more funds to our testnets from some donations: https://twitter.com/MyCrypto/status/1346539474725945344

Our current balances are

```
{
    "network": "ropsten",
    "balance": "10002315.260285"
}, {
    "network": "rinkeby",
    "balance": "1544.5306212239998"
}, {
    "network": "kovan",
    "balance": "54273.470115000004"
}, {
    "network": "goerli",
    "balance": "10876.255949479963"
}
```

This should last a while (though we had to reduce the payout from 1ETH to 0.5ETH). I hope this helps!